# direction angles

Tags: calculus

Which of the following sets of angles can be the direction angles of a space vector?

$\pi/3, 3\pi/4, 2\pi/3$

$\pi/3, \pi/4, 5\pi/6$

$\pi/2, \pi/4, \pi/4$

30 degrees, 60 degrees, 90 degrees

45 degrees, 60 degrees, 120 degrees

I know that answer but have no idea why the other ones can not be space vectors?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using mathJax (see FAQ). it also helps to share what you've done and your thoughts so that the MSE Community can provide better guidance. Regards

Answer (score 1):

The [direction angles](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/reference/CRC-formulas/node52.html) $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ need to satisfy the identity $$\cos^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \beta +\cos^2 \gamma =1$$

Comment: see thats what i put but it turns out only one of them is a possible space vector

Comment: ok i talked to my teacher and he was wrong so my headache is know over